# Angularjs $http.get return 409 error, samething works in postman and crul command

Tags: angularjs, http

I am using forgerock rest api to get user info openam/json/users/userid. testing the rest api on the postman or curl command both works great. however, when i try to do this in angularjs $http.get. it always return the 409 error code.

One more thing to mention is that if i click the error under chrome browser, it open up a new window and show all the result(another way to say is if i simply paste this get rest api on browser url bar, it works).

```
$http.get('/openam/json/users/userId', {header: {"iPlanetDirectoryPro": ssoToken}}).then(function (response) {
                ;
              });
```

Also, if i am use jquery ajax call in angularjs, it works

```
$.ajax({

                url : '/openam/json/users/userId',
                type : 'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                success : function(data) {  

                }
            });
```

Comment: try to use it like this, the problem is the option (header) that you're sending in,

$http.get('/openam/json/users/userId', {headers: {'iPlanetDirectoryPro': ssoToken}}).then(function (response) {
                ;
              });

Comment: i am using angularjs 1.2, the header is actually populate correctly on browswer. however, the headers for this is optional. so, even after i removed the header(as you can see it on the ajar call), i am getting same error. another thing is that if i change this to another rest api, it works.

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting? You can get the same error code but in the message you can see more details, please add more details